# How to append a dataframe to another one (with the same column size) when the column names are different

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to merge two dataframes with the same number of columns but with different names? The `concat`, `merge`, and `join` methods do not seem to work for this task. For example, I want to combine these two:

```
#dataframe1:
columnA | columnB
15      | 23

#dataframe2:
columnC | columnD
12      | 29
```

Into this:

```
#dataframe3:
anyColumnName1 | anyColumnName1
15             | 23
12             | 29
```

Please note that I have **90 columns** in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rename the columns of the second dataframe first.

If they have the same number of columns then simply:

`dataframe2.columns = dataframe1.columns`

and then concat them.

Comment: I choose as the answer since the others does not deal with large column number. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, It is always hard choose one in 3 perfect answers ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
print (np.concatenate([df1, df2]))
[[15 23]
 [12 29]]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([df1, df2]), columns=['a','b'])
print (df)
    a   b
0  15  23
1  12  29
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `append` by renaming columns of second dataframe based on first.

```
In [304]: df1.append(df2.rename(columns=dict(zip(df2.columns, df1.columns))))
Out[304]:
   columnA  columnB
0       15       23
0       12       29
```

Details.

```
In [308]: df1
Out[308]:
   columnA  columnB
0       15       23

In [309]: df2
Out[309]:
   columnC  columnD
0       12       29

In [310]: dict(zip(df2.columns, df1.columns))
Out[310]: {'columnC': 'columnA', 'columnD': 'columnB'}

In [311]: df2.rename(columns=dict(zip(df2.columns, df1.columns)))
Out[311]:
   columnA  columnB
0       12       29
```